# javascript/jQuery Double Submit Prevention method disables initiation of html5 attributes (e.g. Required, Pattern, etc.)

Tags: html, double-submit-prevention

The javascript/jQuery double submit prevention method I use is this:

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
    $("#btnsubmit").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#postform').submit();
});
```

So on submit `click`, the `Submit Button` is `disabled` and the form is submit. So double submit of the form will not happen. BUT. The problem now is that the html5 attributes will not initiate (e.g. Required, Pattern, etc.)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

or maybe you can suggest alternative double submit prevention method that will not tamper with the html5 attributes?

EDIT + DANIEL PATZ ANSWER:

```
$('#postform').on('submit', function (e) {
    // THIS PART
    var titleLength = $("#title").val().length;
    var descriptionLength = $("#description").val().length;
    if(titleLength < 20 || descriptionLength < 150) {
        $("#ps").text("Title and Desc Problem.");
    } else {
    // UNTIL HERE
        $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you catch the `submit` event, it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/tcc7u/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input required /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry was just testing it and forgot to remove the e.

Comment: one last question! I want to add a few jquery validation. how do I and where do I insert it? I tried dabbling with your example but the problem is that my jquery validates but the form will still submit. See Edit

Comment: Never mind my edit i'll add focusout functions to validate instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you add e.preventDefault(); inside of that if, you can stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `$(this).find('[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);` ?